# Problem in a Pell equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

If you take the continued fraction out of $\sqrt7$, you get [2;1, 1, 1, 4...] which yields:
$$2+\frac1{1+\frac1{\frac11+1}}=\frac8{3}$$
and indeed, $$8^2-7⋅3^2=1$$
However, if you take the continued fraction out of $\sqrt13$ you get [3;1, 1, 1, 1, 6...] which yields: $$3+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{\frac11+1}}}=\frac{18}5$$
but that gets $$18^2-13⋅5^2=\textbf{-1}$$not $\textbf{1}$ but $\textbf{-1}$! Why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: The convergents don't always converge to the root from below, here they oscillate.

Comment: If the period of the continued fraction is even, you'll get $+1$, if it's odd, it will be $-1$. In that case, the convergents after an even number of periods yield the solutions for $x^2 -dy^2 = +1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ you are guaranteed to get $-1$ first, but get back to $1$ if you repeat the periodic part of the CF.

Note $$18^2 + 13 \cdot 5^2 = 649,$$
$$ 2 \cdot 18 \cdot 5 = 180, $$
$$ 649^2 - 13 \cdot 180^2 = 1. $$

The continued fraction for $\sqrt {13}$ in the display I like. For a convergent $p/q,$ the number directly below is $p^2 - 13 q^2.$ This includes the fake convergent $1/0,$ which needs to be there to start the process.

$$
\small  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{3}{1} &  &  \frac{4}{1} & &  \frac{7}{2}  & & \frac{11}{3} & &  \frac{18}{5} & &   \frac{119}{33}  & &   \frac{137}{38}  & &   \frac{256}{71}   & &   \frac{393}{109}  & &   \frac{649}{180}   & &   \frac{4287}{1189}  \\
              \\
 & 1 & & -4 &  &  3 & &  -3  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -3  & &   3   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc $$
$$  2^2 - 5 \cdot 1^2 = -1,$$
$$2^2 + 5 \cdot 1^2 = 9,$$
$$ 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 4, $$
$$ 9^2 - 5 \cdot 4^2 = 1. $$
$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc $$
$$  70^2 - 29 \cdot 13^2 = -1,$$
$$70^2 + 29 \cdot 13^2 = 9801,$$
$$ 2 \cdot 70 \cdot 13 = 1820, $$
$$ 9801^2 - 29 \cdot 1820^2 = 1. $$

I put a complete picture for $\sqrt {29}$ at [Solving Diophantine Equation - odd Periods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393247/solving-diophantine-equation-odd-periods/1394771#1394771)

Comment: why these $\bigcirc$'s?

Comment: @janmarqz, just to visually separate the calculations for 13, 5, 29

Comment: Please notice that "p≡1(mod 4)" is not a must, like 99*99 - 58*13*13 == -1 or 43*43 - 74*5*5 and many more.
But I have to hugely thank you for helping me with the 66 euler problem!

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{q_n}{k_n}$ is the nth convergent to the continued fraction, the we have the following equality:

$k_nq_{n-1}-k_{n-1}q_n=(-1)^n$.

So you should choose an even convergent.